# windows phone 7, selectedindex and propertychanged event problem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, listbox, selectedindex

I am having this problem with my listbox, notifypropertychange event, and setting the selectedindex = -1 upon the transition to the next page.

Basically, I select an item from a list. In doing so it opens up to another page to give details about the item. When I select the item, however, I need to make the selectedindex set to -1 after it transitions to the details page.

Yet, when I write the code, once it hits the selectedindex = -1; line, it calls the function again due to the propertychange event firing. Then it passes a null value to the details page, where the application breaks.

Here is my relevant code:

list of feeds to select from. Once you select a particular one, Listbox_SelectionChanged fires.

```
  public UserSubmitted()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                  {
                      this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
                  };
    }

    private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
       {
               NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PivotPage1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
               hello.SelectedIndex = -1;   //hello = listbox name.
       }
```

This is what is called next, which is my ViewData Model. It begins at the PropertyChanged event, and then compares the sender. It then proceeds to set the SelectedItem.

```
  public ObservableCollection<RssItem> FeedItems
    {
        get { return _feedItems; }

        set
        {
            if (_feedItems == value)
                return;
            _feedItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FeedItems"));
        }
    }

    public string FeedTitle
    {
        get { return _FeedTitle; }
        set
        {
            if (_FeedTitle == value)
                return;
            _FeedTitle = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FeedTitle"));
        }
    }

    public RssItem SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedItem == value)
                return;
            _SelectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(sender, args);
    }
```

It then proceeds to go to the line: hello.SelectedIndex = 1; where it goes through the above code again, but passing everything as null (as it's all set to -1).

Then it proceeds to pass this information to the pivot page (the details page).

```
    public PivotPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
                this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
                var selectedItem = App.ViewModel.SelectedItem;
                var pi = ItemPivot.Items.First(p => p == selectedItem);  //breaks here as null.
                ItemPivot.SelectedItem = pi;
            };
    }
```

anyone know why this is?

Comment: Could you give us the reasoning why you need to set the SelectedIndex to -1 in the first place?

Comment: of course. When selecting the particular feed from the selection, in order to view the details, and when going to the details, if I hit the back button on the details I cannot select the same feed once at the selection.

Comment: so it's the problem of going to it, coming back, and not being able to select the same feed. So if I select the feed at location index of 47 (the 48th feed), I look at the details and go back, I am unable to select the 48th feed until until I change the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd check in the listbox_SelectionChanged method whether the selected index is already -1. If it is, then just return and do nothing.

```
private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (hello.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PivotPage1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    hello.SelectedIndex = -1;   //hello = listbox name.
}
```